# Routing pages via side-menu in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, router-outlet, ion-nav

```
     For days now I've been trying to route/link pages via the side-menu. So that I'm able to move to different pages from the side-menu itself. I've searched for tutorials on Angular 8 and Ionic 4 but couldn't find the specific article that relates to my issue.
```

I'm supposing to route pages by creating components of the pages(items that will on the side-menu) for easier routing. I also somewhat know what codes to use for routing but don't know where to use it, since using the codes in the wrong place won't provide me any resolution.

`This is my app.component.ts file.`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule, routeComponents } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, routeComponents],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Below is the `app-routing.module.ts` file.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TrackComponent } from './track/track.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category/category.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.component').then( m => 
m.HomeComponent)},
  { path: 'category', loadChildren: () => import('./category/category.component').then( m => 
m.CategoryComponent)},
  { path: 'track', loadChildren: () => import('./track/track.component').then( m => 
m.TrackComponent)},
  { path: 'about', loadChildren: () => import('./about/about.component').then( m => 
m.AboutComponent)}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routeComponents = [CategoryComponent, TrackComponent, AboutComponent, 
HomeComponent];
```

Please let me know if I also need to modify the html files for each menu-item. If possible please try to explain it to me in **layman's term.**

Comment: There is no relation in ionic in app.module , you provided wrong given instead so edit  it. And routing can be used where you want. If you are in ts file then this.router.navigate(["track"]); and if from html add attribute routerLink="/track" . Is that what you need?

Comment: But the `app-routing.module.ts` is built by itself when creating/starting an app/page for the routing . through out the app. And where should I add `this.router.navigate(["track"]);` line.

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 0):

In ts file:

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private router:Router){}
navtigateToPage(pageName){
 this.router.navigate([pageName]);
}
```

In html file:

```
<ion-item (click)="navtigateToPage('track')">
<ion-label>track</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

(click) can be added to any node element (div,span,ion-icon...)